# How Use HomeBrew with macOS 10.12

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-sierra

How to use Homebrew with macOS 10.12 ?

I got message

```
==> You are using macOS 10.12.
==> We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
```

are there some ways to use it ?